# run eclipse docker tooling with Podman backend on Windows

Tags: eclipse, docker, podman

want to use Eclipse with Podman backend on Windows. I have Podman Desktop installed and the podman context is:

Name                         URI                                                          Identity                                    Default
podman-machine-default       ssh://user@localhost:64926/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock  C:\Users\me.ssh\podman-machine-default  true
podman-machine-default-root  ssh://root@localhost:64926/run/podman/podman.sock            C:\Users\me.ssh\podman-machine-default  false

Eclipse's Docker tooling has a setting for Container engine like the following:

[image]

It takes either a unix socket or a TCP connection, but none of them accept the value specified by Podman URI like ssh://user@localhost:64926/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock.

Is there a workaround I can connect Eclipse to Podman engine on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [workaround](https://lists.podman.io/archives/list/podman@lists.podman.io/message/W26TZQLT5CA6XG5FGMWR7Z6CASTPFYDP/) that I learned from Red Hat engineer Jason Greene to make Eclipse Docker Tooling (EDT) work with Podman as a backend:
First, create a ssh connection to the podman machine with the L flag and expose a TCP proxy on a specific port.

```
podman machine ssh -- "-L5555:/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock" -N
```

Then, in the TCP connection section of New Docker Connection dialog enter:
`tcp://localhost:5555`. The tooling will connect to the remote podman engine and can perform container operations.